# Jquery mobile Pre-loaded page Stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

My actually problem is below.I would be happy if this is solved.

I Want to know why jquery Preloaded url stops working.Below are steps to replicate my problem.

1. visit http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/ .
2. Type "m"
3. You get list of names.Click any one.
4. For example i clicked http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/target.html?term=Maryland.
5. Now why Select tool is not working after page preload.
6. If i reload http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/target.html?term=Maryland It works fine

[image]
7.  But if its preloaded whats the reason it stops working.

If that cannot be resolved , Tell me if any function available to stop the preload for single page.

Comment: The code here is a bit odd but I would first look into your "base" tag at the top of your code. I think it might be breaking your links. You seem to be swapping the url with javascript somewhere and it doesn't actually get instantiated into the html until you do a refresh. Hope that makes sense hard to explain lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this works, but you could use the `data-ajax="false"` attr on links and form actions

Comment: whats the reason preloaded page stops working ?

Comment: by the way, i don't see target on links, just an '#' (<a href="target.html'> or Id, or onclick function)

Answer (score 1):

You have placed selectmenu `change` event inside `.ready()`, which shouldn't be used in jQuery mobile. The equivalent event is `pageinit`.

Also, instead of using `window.location.href`, use `$.mobile.chagnePage()` to activate Ajax navigation that jQuery Mobile uses.

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#mainPage", function () {
  $("#examples").on("change", function () {
    var page = $(this).val();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $.mobile.changePage(page);
    }, 100);
  });
});
```

Comment: no not working please check http://freegifts.in/auto/autoComplete.js-master/index.html

Comment: @Vishnu place code.js in `head`.

Comment: yea its in head , but still its not working :/

Comment: @Vishnu jquery is omitting an error, let me check it.

Comment: @Vishnu place this outside setTimeout `var value = $(this).val();` and in `$.mobile.changePage(value);` its a setTimeout problem. I've updated my answer.

Comment: hey omar ! still it wont work for me :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46270/discussion-between-omar-and-vishnu)

Answer (score 1):

Just update your `code.js` `on` event handler to:

`$('body').on('change', '#examples', function(e, ui) {`

It'll work! Tested here.